# pygtk textview getbuffer and write at the same time

Tags: python, multithreading, textview, pygtk

I am trying to make a program(in python) that as I write it writes to a file and opens to a certain window that I have already created.I have looked allarund for a vaible soution bt it would seem that multi-threading may be the only option.

I was hoping that when option autorun is "activated" it will:

```
while 1:
    wbuffer = textview.get_buffer()
    text = wbuffer.get_text(wbuffer.get_start_iter(), wbuffer.get_end_iter())
    openfile = open(filename,"w")
    openfile.write(text)
    openfile.close()
```

I am using pygtk and have a textview window, but when I get the buffer it sits forever.
I am thinking that I need to multi-thread it and queue it so one thread will be writing the buffer while it is being queued.

my source is [here](http://pastebin.com/UN35VHDD). (I think the statement is at line 177.)

any help is much appreciated. :)

and here is the function:

```
def autorun(save):
    filename = None
    chooser = gtk.FileChooserDialog("Save File...", None,
                                    gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SAVE,
                                    (gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL,
                                     gtk.STOCK_SAVE, gtk.RESPONSE_OK))

    response = chooser.run()
    if response == gtk.RESPONSE_OK: filename = chooser.get_filename()
    filen = filename
    addr = (filename)
    addressbar.set_text("file://" + filename)
    web.open(addr)
    chooser.destroy()
    wbuffer = textview.get_buffer()
    while 1:
      text = wbuffer.get_text(wbuffer.get_start_iter(), wbuffer.get_end_iter())
      time.sleep(1)
      openfile = open(filename,"w")
      openfile.write(text)
      openfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not too easy to see exactly what your GTK-stuff not included here is doing, the main problem is that the control needs to be returned to the gtk main-loop. Else the program will hang.

So if you have a long process (like this eternal one here), then you need to thread it. The problem is that you need the thread to exit nicely when the main program quits, so you'll have to redesign a bit around that. Also, threading with gtk needs to be initialized correctly (look [here](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/gdk-functions.html#function-gdk--threads-init)).

However, I don't think you need threading, instead you could connect the `changed` signal of your `TextBuffer` to a function that writes the buffer to the target-file (if the user has put the program in `autorun`-mode). A problem with this is if the buffer gets large or program slow, in which case, you should consider threading the callback of the `changed` signal. So this solution requires to make sure you don't get into the situation where save-requests get stacked on top of each other because the user is faster at typing than the computer is saving. Takes some design thought.

**So, finally, the easier solution:** you may not want the buffer to save for every button-press. In which case, you could have the save-function (which could look like your first code-block without the loop) on a [timeout](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--timeout-add) instead. Just don't make the time-out too short.

Comment: Yes, you're right except from what it looks like Textview doesn't have a "changed"signal but get_buffer does! so what I am doing is I created a new function that is a button that when pressed activates the other function     def xrun(x):
 xbuffer = textview.get_buffer()
 xbuffer.connect("changed",autorun)... sorry the edit on on this window is terrible. thank you! you made my day!

Comment: TextView doesn't have changed, the TextBuffer has.